# Can you win 2 awards with one product?

Tags: android, anime-studio-story

In `Kairosoft`'s mobile games, like `Game Dev Story` and `Anime Studio Story`, is it possible to win 2 award with the same game/anime in the awards ceremony?

Can you win the grand prize after you've won Best Sound or Best Graphics award?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.  Did it myself multiple times :) you can even win 3.

Comment: You can win three, but my understanding is that each series you create can only win a single award.

Comment: Exactly. The question is can you win two or more awards for the same series in the same ceremony? I've played hours, got one of each prize, but not two for the same series.